# Selection of category and value through text box?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, user-experience

I would like to enable an alternate text box (similar to the Tags one that we have here on StackOverflow) with a small variation that the user should be able to specify a category for the tag they are entering. What I mean is the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| gender: male*, state: ----------------          | <--- this is a textbox
-----------------------|--------------|-----------
                       | Illinois     |
                       | Washington   |
                       ----------------
```

To explain verbatim, the user gets presented with suggestions when they start entering "g" (show "gender"), they can select that and move on to ":" after which suggestions for gender (i.e., "male" and "female") are shown. The user can add as many tags as they want and will be shown with an "x" (* was used in the above picture) to remove that tag.

Is there any work on enabling this experience? I am particularly interested in implementations that build on Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest angular ui-select [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXOwv6?p=info)

```
.
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is using [ui.bootstrap.typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to search through list of data.
and add [bootstrap label](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) after selection is done.